# Can Java Web Start run terminal applications?

Tags: java, java-web-start

As mentioned I am trying to create a java application that is done primarily through CLI, I don't want to build a swing application as I will be using text based input for 99% of the work.

I've tried setting up a Java Web Start file through my IDE and it works for Swing applications but it is unable to run a "Hello World!" program that outputs Hello World to the screen and asks for the users name via `System.in`. I've read the Java Web Start website and it does not mention anywhere that terminal style apps are not possible. Is anyone able to help here?

(I'd be willing to embed the standard I/O stuff you do inside a `JFrame` if this was fairly simple).

For the sake of reference I used [the following tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-jws.html) which worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Launch the app. using JWS without a GUI & you would not have access to the command line for the input/output.  So - no, not really practical.